# Solidus - cannot upload or view images (ImageMagick is installed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip, spree, solidus

I'm just starting with Solidus, though I do know my way around Rails. I've created a Solidus project on my Mac, and I installed all the required gems as well as ImageMagick through Homebrew.  Both `identify` and `magick` work as terminal commands as my `/usr/local/bin` directory is in my PATH. I've also specified the path to `identify` in the `application.rb` file (I'm guessing it's supposed to go in side the `Application` class). However, none of the images show up in Solidus, and when I try and manually add an image, I get the following error (it's related to paperclip). Any help here would be - Google has not been my friend this time. The error message is shown below:

```
[paperclip] Trying to link /tmp/RackMultipart20200622-9041-8gndhx.jpg to /tmp/cdcf58ad03be2998ea64da8e6cd3e43c20200622-9041-1t35lnu.jpg
[paperclip] Trying to link /tmp/cdcf58ad03be2998ea64da8e6cd3e43c20200622-9041-1t35lnu.jpg to /tmp/cdcf58ad03be2998ea64da8e6cd3e43c20200622-9041-62aumc.jpg
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/identify:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/cdcf58ad03be2998ea64da8e6cd3e43c20200622-9041-62aumc.jpg'
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/identify:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/cdcf58ad03be2998ea64da8e6cd3e43c20200622-9041-1t35lnu.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/identify:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/cdcf58ad03be2998ea64da8e6cd3e43c20200622-9041-1t35lnu.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/identify:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/cdcf58ad03be2998ea64da8e6cd3e43c20200622-9041-1t35lnu.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/identify:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/cdcf58ad03be2998ea64da8e6cd3e43c20200622-9041-1t35lnu.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
[paperclip] Trying to link /tmp/cdcf58ad03be2998ea64da8e6cd3e43c20200622-9041-1t35lnu.jpg to /tmp/cdcf58ad03be2998ea64da8e6cd3e43c20200622-9041-1dlkgdw.jpg
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/identify:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/cdcf58ad03be2998ea64da8e6cd3e43c20200622-9041-1dlkgdw.jpg'
[paperclip] Trying to link /tmp/cdcf58ad03be2998ea64da8e6cd3e43c20200622-9041-1t35lnu.jpg to /tmp/cdcf58ad03be2998ea64da8e6cd3e43c20200622-9041-16yjulo.jpg
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/identify:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/cdcf58ad03be2998ea64da8e6cd3e43c20200622-9041-16yjulo.jpg'
  Rendering /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/solidus_backend-2.10.1/app/views/spree/admin/images/create.js.erb
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/solidus_backend-2.10.1/app/views/spree/admin/images/create.js.erb (Duration: 3.4ms | Allocations: 874)
Completed 200 OK in 836ms (Views: 20.7ms | ActiveRecord: 7.6ms | Allocations: 29100)
```

Comment: Are you trying to upload an image or do some other kind of processing with paperclip?
When is `identify` being called?

Comment: I'm trying to upload images to Solidus. It's called by one of the controllers in the spree backend ([code available here](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/tree/master/backend/app/controllers/spree/admin).) I've tried it on both my Windows laptop running Debian WSL and on my Mac. Same result each time.